# how to Genrate id at the time when data is insert into database in mvc

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

How to generate an `id` in MVC when the data is inserted into a database? 
example :
i have table in sql tblexample .tblcolumn nid,code,name nid is auto increment and primary key when user insert data into database than only pass name to sql and save name but after insert data code genrate like code="c100"+nid and update in code column using mvc.

Comment: Is this your question ?

Comment: yes sir its my question

Comment: You can use trigger instead

Comment: this question is not related to the tag you specified. it is related to database

Comment: Are you using Entity framework or Ado.net ??

Comment: yes i am using entity framework

Answer (score 0):

You can generate like custom autoincrement as,

Follow all the steps from this [link](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/)

And adjust some changes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use, Entitiy Freamwork

Firstly define string poco as P.K. and in Ef, poco classess

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string id{ get; set; }
```

After this, programaticly you can generate your Id.

By the way, be careafull about previous generated keys :) Look always last Pk before generate new one.